# Let G be $\mathbb Z_p\times\dots\times \mathbb Z_p$. Find $A(G)$ (the Automorphism group of $G$).

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

Let G be $\underbrace{\mathbb Z_p\times\dots\times \mathbb Z_p}_{n \text{ times}}$. Find $A(G)$ (the Automorphism group of $G$).

($\mathbb Z_p$ is the integres modulo p, for example $\mathbb Z_2=\{0,1\},\ \  \mathbb Z_5=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$)

I thoght about:

Think about $(\mathbb Z_p)^n$ as vector space over $\mathbb Z_p$ of dimension n. Then to think about the automorphisms as linear transformations  (do I need to explain it more?). So $A(\mathbb Z_p)^n$ is equal to to the space of all invertible linear transformations of $(\mathbb Z_p)^n$ to itself. 
Then we get that $A(G)\cong GL_n(\mathbb Z_p)$.

is that enough or I need to add something?

Comment: A group is a $\Bbb Z$-module. In our case, the $\Bbb Z$-module structure indeces a $\Bbb F_p$-module structure, i.e. we have a vector space over the finite field $\Bbb F_p$ with $p$ elements. A $\Bbb Z$-module automorphism is an $\Bbb F_p$-automorphism. So the above argumentation is ok.

Comment: I think that for completeness you must (a) show that there is a unique way of making the abelian group into an $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space; and (b) show that  any abelian-group homomorphism is then an $\mathbb{F}_p$ linear transformation.

Comment: why I need to add it? and how do I do it?

Comment: I don't see the difference in the answers so mine is enough?